# Bxslider how enable and disable responsive

Tags: bxslider

I used bxslider and match-height to create "Gallery Grid Slider Responsive with equal height box".

It works. But the problem is not responsive changing "**550px wide 2 columns and 3 rows**" to "**450px wide 1 column and 1 row**". It only works when its load.

Can I remove the bxslider and do function again responsively?

```
(function() {
         /* matchHeight example */
        $(function() {
         // apply your matchHeight on DOM ready (they will be automatically re-applied on load or resize)
         var byRow = $('.item-wrapper').hasClass('match-rows');
        // apply matchHeight to each item container's items
        $('.item-container').each(function() {
            $(this).children('.item-query').matchHeight({
                 byRow: byRow
            });
            });
      if($(window).width() > 450 && !$(".bx-s").length){
        var divs = jQuery(".item-container .item-query");
          for(var i = 0; i < divs.length; i+=6) {
            divs.slice(i, i+6).wrapAll("<div class='bx-s'></div>");
          }
      }else{
            $(".bx-s .item-query").unwrap();
      }
      $('.item-container').bxSlider({
          nextSelector: '#item-nav-right',
          prevSelector: '#item-nav-left',
          pager: false,
          nextText: 'next',
          prevText: 'prev'
        });
        });
    })();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/k55y6c9h/1/

Comment: In your demo, bxSlider is not functioning (Chrome PC). Each `.item-query` is a slide of a single element called `.item-container`.  All `.item-query` elements are displayed as a grid.

Comment: Okay. Let me check and update it.

Comment: Here's the new update. https://jsfiddle.net/k55y6c9h/1/